# How to get the app from background to foreground in xamarn ui test

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am trying to automate mobile app test scenarios using Xamarin UI test and I have one scenario that whenever I click on call button, Dial key pad will open and my app goes to background and rest of the scenarios are failing with error no element found. How can I make app to foreground in order to run remaining scenarios?
I'm using below command to connect to the app but still app remains in background

```
ConfigureApp.Android.ConnectToApp();
```

Comment: Once your app is in background, it is no longer in control. Therefore your UI.Test code is also not in control (I think). AFAIK, the only solution is to "mock" that action during testing. I don’t know the details for the environment you are in, but the concept is that your code checks if running a test, and if so, doesn’t actually do the action that took app to background. Instead returns a value as if user interacted with background entity. One way this is done is via a "mock" object.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Thanks for your response. I am using below command in order to execute remaining tests and app builds from beginning.
ConfigureApp.Android.StartApp(AppDataMode.DoNotClear)